# How to fix/reset windows manager?

Tags: kali-linux, xfce, window-manager, xfwm4

I am unable to see the running applications in the panel. I can't switch between open windows. How can I fix it? I tried to open windows manager and windows tweak manager but they won't open. So far I have tried resetting Xfce settings and using dconf-editor to reset all settings to default which didn't work either.
Please help.

Comment: running command `xfwm4` started the windows manager and then it simply worked. For some reason, `xfwm4` doesn't start on the boot and I have to manually start the service.

Answer (score 0):

Run `xfmw4 --replace` and then reboot.